# Writing to a COM port with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, php, arduino

How would I go about writing to a COM port, trying to convert the [following example](http://www.arduinoprojects.com/?q=node/10) to .Net (C#), specifically the PHP part?  If possible is there an easier way to write out to a USB?

Comment: You can't write a COM port.  You can connect to to a COM port, and you can listen to a COM port, but you can't write a COM port, for the same reason that you can't write a mouse.

Comment: Of course you can write to a COM port! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline.aspx

Comment: @Rob, yes, you can write to a COM port, but you can't write the COM port itself.  The question used to ask how to write a COM port, without the word _to_.

Comment: Slaks, I only see _writing __to__ a COMport_ in the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing link , not sure the down vote was required though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the SerialPort class, e.g.:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1");
port.Open();
if (port.IsOpen)
{
}
port.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

see [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest** way to write to USB is through serial port (COMx - on windows).
Here are some examples in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the [`System.IO.Ports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.aspx)  namespace docs:

> The System.IO.Ports namespace contains classes for controlling serial ports. The most important class, SerialPort, provides a framework for synchronous and event-driven I/O, access to pin and break states, and access to serial driver properties. It can be used to wrap a Stream objects, allowing the serial port to be accessed by classes that use streams.
>
> The namespace includes enumerations that simplify the control of serial ports, such as Handshake, Parity, SerialPinChange, and StopBits.

The [`SerialPort` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) documentation contains a detailed usage exmaple.